# Rails - How can I select records and those records has_many children without the query returning duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

given these models

```
ModelOne
    has_many :model_twos

ModelTwo
    belongs_to :model_one

    string :field_one
```

and given these records

```
model_twos
    id  field_one  model_one_id
    1  "val 1"     1
    2  "val 2"     1
    3  "val 3"     1
    4  "val 4"     2
    5  "val 5"     2
    6  "val 6"     2
```

how can I retrieve all `model_ones` and those `model_ones` `model_twos` `field_one` values in one query without it returning 3 instances of each `model_one`

I've tried various permutations of `ModelOne.joins("LEFT JOIN model_twos ON model_twos.model_one_id = model_ones.id").select("DISTINCT model_ones.*, model_twos.field_one as model_two_field_one")` but none give the result I'm looking for

I'd like a rails way to do it, but I would also be happy with a sql query that would work

Comment: ModelOne.all.includes(:model_two)

Comment: that still results in a situation where I'll have to make calls back to the database to retrieve the `field_one` values, I need that `model_one`'s `model_twos`' `field_one` values to be returned with it

Comment: No I am pretty sure that will allow you to access field_one without recalling the db.

Comment: You're right in that when you get a specific `model_one`'s `model_twos`' `field_one` but not when you try to pluck all the `field_ones` from a `model_one`'s `model_twos`. I could loop through all the `model_ones` and then loop through each of their `model_twos` and pull out their `field_one` one by one, but I'm trying to avoid doing that

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using

`ModelOne.joins("LEFT JOIN model_twos ON model_twos.model_one_id = model_ones.id").select("DISTINCT model_ones.*, (SELECT array(SELECT model_twos.field_one FROM model_twos WHERE model_twos.model_one_id = model_ones.id)) as model_two_field_one")`